nuxt-auth failed to build on Cloudflare
Nuxt3 with Sidebase nuxt-auth deployment on Cloudflare Pages problem. it runs as expected on local dev environment, but failed to build on Cloudflare deployment.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
Here's the package.json
{ "name": "nuxthub-starter", "private": true, "type": "module", "scripts": { "dev": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env.local", "build": "nuxt build", "preview": "nuxt preview", "deploy": "nuxthub deploy", "postinstall": "nuxt prepare", "lint": "eslint .", "typecheck": "nuxt typecheck" }, "dependencies": { "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2", "zod": "^3.22.4", "@cloudflare/ai": "^1.0.47", "@nuxt/content": "^2.12.1", "@nuxt/eslint": "^0.3.8", "@nuxthub/core": "^0.5.11", "markdown-it": "^14.0.0", "markdown-it-abbr": "^2.0.0", "markdown-it-anchor": "^8.6.7", "markdown-it-footnote": "^4.0.0", "markdown-it-highlightjs": "^4.0.1", "markdown-it-sub": "^2.0.0", "markdown-it-sup": "^2.0.0", "markdown-it-task-lists": "^2.1.1", "markdown-it-toc-done-right": "^4.2.0", "nuxt": "^3.11.2", "nuxt-security": "^1.3.1", "sass": "^1.72.0", "vue": "^3.4.21", "vue-router": "^4.3.0", "wrangler": "^3.55.0" }, "devDependencies": { "@nuxt/eslint-config": "^0.3.8", "@sidebase/nuxt-auth": "^0.7.2", "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6", "eslint": "^9.0.0", "vue-tsc": "^2.0.13", "nitro-cloudflare-dev": "^0.1.1" } }
Here's the deployment log file from Cloudflare Dashboard.
2024-05-19T07:20:59.109713Z Cloning repository...
2024-05-19T07:21:00.006598Z From [taken away the github repo link]
2024-05-19T07:21:00.007024Z  * branch            93f3d052a1a1e2129d9b82d75f2f20fcbd11d69c -> FETCH_HEAD
2024-05-19T07:21:00.007133Z
2024-05-19T07:21:00.039908Z HEAD is now at 82a3e12 added sidebase/nuxt-auth
2024-05-19T07:21:00.040278Z
2024-05-19T07:21:00.126243Z
2024-05-19T07:21:00.127292Z Using v2 root directory strategy
2024-05-19T07:21:00.15177Z  Success: Finished cloning repository files
2024-05-19T07:21:01.682119Z Checking for configuration in a wrangler.toml configuration file (BETA)
2024-05-19T07:21:01.68277Z
2024-05-19T07:21:01.682893Z Found wrangler.toml file. Reading build configuration...
2024-05-19T07:21:01.688331Z pages_build_output_dir: dist
2024-05-19T07:21:01.688529Z Build environment variables: (none found)
2024-05-19T07:21:01.787849Z Successfully read wrangler.toml file.
2024-05-19T07:21:01.935828Z Detected the following tools from environment: npm@9.6.7, nodejs@18.17.1
2024-05-19T07:21:01.936422Z Installing project dependencies: npm clean-install --progress=false
2024-05-19T07:21:03.790751Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.791571Z npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.791818Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.791971Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792309Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792399Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792603Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792744Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792885Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.792967Z npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793086Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-config@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793233Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793375Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793455Z npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793705Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.793851Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.794002Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.794142Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-config@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.794267Z npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config
2024-05-19T07:21:03.798332Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.798506Z npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/parser@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.79865Z  npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.798748Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.798852Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.798952Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.79904Z  npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799148Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799275Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799388Z npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799495Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-config@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799624Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799737Z npm WARN   1 more (@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.799884Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.800003Z npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.80015Z  npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.800396Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.800574Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
2024-05-19T07:21:03.800748Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-config@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.800953Z npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config
2024-05-19T07:21:03.801082Z npm WARN     1 more (@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.804402Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.804726Z npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.804931Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805133Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805271Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805373Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805493Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805619Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805733Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805839Z npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.805977Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-plugin@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806092Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806192Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806296Z npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806406Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806563Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806697Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806812Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @nuxt/eslint-plugin@0.3.12
2024-05-19T07:21:03.806915Z npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.810899Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81108Z  npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811199Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811309Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811431Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811553Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811656Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811773Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.811886Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812032Z npm WARN node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81217Z  npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus@2.1.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812291Z npm WARN   node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812406Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812664Z npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812794Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.812918Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81302Z  npm WARN   node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.813131Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus@2.1.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.813232Z npm WARN     node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-plus
2024-05-19T07:21:03.816852Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817243Z npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817398Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817515Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817644Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817741Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.817837Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81794Z  npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818035Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818137Z npm WARN node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818241Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@2.1.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818329Z npm WARN   node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818432Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81853Z  npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818649Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.81874Z  npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818834Z npm WARN   node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.818931Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.8.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@2.1.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.819132Z npm WARN     node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
2024-05-19T07:21:03.821567Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.82185Z  npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.821992Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822112Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822246Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822402Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822551Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822686Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822831Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.822983Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-import-x/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.823149Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.4.0" from eslint-plugin-import-x@0.5.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.823301Z npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-import-x
2024-05-19T07:21:03.823467Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.82366Z  npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.823834Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.823984Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.824117Z npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-plugin-import-x/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.824248Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/utils@"^7.4.0" from eslint-plugin-import-x@0.5.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.824403Z npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-plugin-import-x
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827125Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827266Z npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827396Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827508Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827692Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827808Z npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.827939Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828047Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828152Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828248Z npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828341Z npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"7.8.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828429Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828514Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.82862Z  npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828703Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828786Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828892Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.828987Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"7.8.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.829084Z npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.833552Z npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83375Z  npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.833864Z npm WARN Found: eslint@9.2.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83397Z  npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834061Z npm WARN   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83416Z  npm WARN   17 more (@eslint-community/eslint-utils, ...)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834257Z npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834352Z npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834482Z npm WARN peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834668Z npm WARN node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.8348Z   npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.8.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.834965Z npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.835037Z npm WARN   1 more (@typescript-eslint/type-utils)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83546Z  npm WARN
2024-05-19T07:21:03.835664Z npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.835824Z npm WARN node_modules/eslint
2024-05-19T07:21:03.835936Z npm WARN   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83601Z  npm WARN   node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
2024-05-19T07:21:03.836112Z npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.8.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0
2024-05-19T07:21:03.836213Z npm WARN     node_modules/@nuxt/eslint-config/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
2024-05-19T07:21:03.836283Z npm WARN     1 more (@typescript-eslint/type-utils)
2024-05-19T07:21:03.838457Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.838785Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint/eslintrc@3.0.2',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.838976Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839122Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839215Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839279Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839486Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@eslint/js@9.2.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.83963Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839741Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839843Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.839957Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.840092Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@humanwhocodes/retry@0.2.4',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.840211Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.18' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.840323Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.840424Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.842163Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.842307Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84243Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.842498Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.842861Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.842952Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843036Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843291Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843395Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843525Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843659Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843745Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.843861Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844023Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84419Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844286Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844393Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/parser@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844581Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84466Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844755Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844874Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.844977Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845082Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845191Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845297Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845405Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845511Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@stylistic/eslint-plugin@2.1.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845796Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.845948Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846066Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846232Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846404Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js@2.1.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846488Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846611Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846731Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846828Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.846927Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@stylistic/eslint-plugin-jsx@2.1.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.847036Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84715Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84729Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.847424Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.847531Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.847639Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84772Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84782Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84792Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848032Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@2.1.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848126Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848222Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848322Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848517Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848605Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848755Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.848869Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849068Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849204Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849324Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/scope-manager@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849454Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849588Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.849703Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.84986Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850006Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/types@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850109Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850238Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850436Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850617Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.850781Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.851071Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.851198Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.851344Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.851733Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.851824Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852105Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852251Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852391Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852496Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852648Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint@9.2.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852743Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.852879Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853083Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853157Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853284Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@typescript-eslint/utils@7.8.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853461Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853635Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853739Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853856Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.853977Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-scope@8.0.1',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.85408Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.8542Z   npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854311Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854431Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854556Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-visitor-keys@4.0.0',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854666Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854789Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.854903Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.855038Z npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2024-05-19T07:21:03.85517Z  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'espree@10.0.1',
2024-05-19T07:21:03.855294Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.18.0 || ^20.9.0 || >=21.1.0' },
2024-05-19T07:21:03.855412Z npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.17.1', npm: '9.6.7' }
2024-05-19T07:21:03.855603Z npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-05-19T07:21:06.768104Z npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
2024-05-19T07:21:06.939174Z npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
2024-05-19T07:21:12.417331Z npm WARN deprecated @cloudflare/ai@1.2.2: Thanks for using @cloudflare/ai: This package has been deprecated in favor of the native binding, learn more here https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers-ai/configuration/bindings/
2024-05-19T07:21:23.290046Z
2024-05-19T07:21:23.290308Z > postinstall
2024-05-19T07:21:23.290433Z > nuxt prepare
2024-05-19T07:21:23.290555Z
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072139Z [error] Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try npm i again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072376Z   at requireWithFriendlyError (node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:59:9)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072452Z   at Object. (node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:68:76)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072515Z   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072601Z   at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072661Z   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072718Z   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072776Z   at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072831Z   at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072893Z
2024-05-19T07:21:24.072957Z [error] Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try npm i again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
2024-05-19T07:21:24.091268Z npm ERR! code 1
2024-05-19T07:21:24.091551Z npm ERR! path /opt/buildhome/repo
2024-05-19T07:21:24.094383Z npm ERR! command failed
2024-05-19T07:21:24.094517Z npm ERR! command sh -c nuxt prepare
2024-05-19T07:21:24.095882Z
2024-05-19T07:21:24.096054Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-05-19T07_21_02_637Z-debug-0.log
2024-05-19T07:21:24.118275Z Error: Exit with error code: 1
2024-05-19T07:21:24.118634Z     at ChildProcess. (/snapshot/dist/run-build.js)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.119129Z     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.119241Z     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.119308Z     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
2024-05-19T07:21:24.132325Z Failed: build command exited with code: 1
2024-05-19T07:21:25.246452Z Failed: error occurred while running build command
